# if value of field is less by 3 points of another field Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an alert that goes out when I have an order Id when the Cost is less then the price.  But I need to get the alert only if the Cost is less by at least $3. This is what I have so far, it works, but I need to figure out how to show the alert only if the Cost is $3.00 less or more then the Price.

```
if@OrderID > 0 and (@Cost < @Price)
```

So to be clear if the Cost is less then the Price by $3 or more. Both are money datatypes.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: MSSMS is the one i am working with

Answer (score 1):

That same line, but subtract $3 from price like this:

`if@OrderID > 0 and (@Cost <= @Price - 3)`

Answer (score 1):

if the module of result is more than 2.

```
if@OrderID > 0 and (ABS(@Cost - @Price) >= 3)
```